# Replace matching pattern only if it's not in a specific place in the content with regex

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

Part of our tools that we are building rely a lot on regex.
Once of the things is replacing placeholders with real values on the fly using standard javascript's `RegExp.

All of our placeholders look something like this:

```
{{key}}
```

In most cases the replacement is strait forward and easy and we build pattern for matching like so:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('{{key}}', 'g');
```

However, there is at lease one case where this approach does not work. Assume that we have an `a` tag with a placeholder in it's href:

```
<a href="http://google.com?q={{key}}">http://google.com?q={{key}}</a>
```

what we need to replace the placeholder with is an html code (in some cases), but as you can imagine, it breaks the markup.

Note: it can potentially be any link or any content inside the link.

How can I replace only the placeholder that is NOT inside the `href`? Is it even possible?

Comment: Match and capture the text you want to keep, just match the text you need to replace. See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/p9c6pL/1), use JS code to manipulate the group contents further.

Comment: Well, this one is pretty specific for this particular case. The placeholders might be anywhere in the content, not only links. I was wondering, if there is a way to find all that are not inside an href attribute.

Comment: Same approach, adjust as per your needs: [`(\shref=['"][^"']*['"])|{{(.*?)}}`](https://regex101.com/r/p9c6pL/2). As with any regex approach used for HTML manipulation, this is not guaranteed to work well in 100% cases.

Comment: So what would you suggest if not regex?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the `{{key}}` inside the `href`, you could either escape the braces, or add support for filters.

Escaping:

```
var values = {"key": "stackoverflow"};
var html = template.replace(/\\([{}\\])|{{(\w+)}}/g, function (match, esc, name) {
    // Remove backslashes from an escaped characters, or replace placeholders
    // by their values.
    return esc ? esc : values[name];
});
```

Example:

```
<a href="http://google.com?q=\{{key}}">http://google.com?q={{key}}</a>
```

Filters:

```
var values = {"key": "stackoverflow"};
var filters = {
    "quote": function (value) {
        return quote.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
    }
};
var html = template.replace(/{{(\w+(?:\s*\|\s*\w+)*)}}/g, function (match, expr) {
    var names = expr.split(/\s*\|\s*/g);
    var value = values[expr[0]];
    for (var i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
        value = filters[name[i]](value);
    }
});
```

Example:

```
<a href="http://google.com?q={{key|quote}}">http://google.com?q={{key}}</a>
```

---

You could also use AngularJS's built-in templates.

```
var templateElm = angular.element("<div>").html(template);

var innerScope = $scope.$new(true);

// Shallow copy values into the scope
angular.extend(innerScope, values);

var elem = $compile(templateElm)(innerScope);

// Wait for automatic $digest to complete
$timeout(function () {
    var html = elem.html();

    innerScope.$destroy();

    // Do something with 'html'
});
```